# How to scale SVG when svg reference another

Tags: html, css, svg

I use inline svg in my project and I want change width and height to use like small icon but use tag dont resize.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid 1px;
}

svg.icon {
  border: solid 1px tomato;
  /**debug*/
  overflow: visible;
}

.icon use {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
  <defs>
      <g id="ico-and">
        <path d="M152.682,458.363c0,15.3,10.2,25.5,25.5,25.5h25.5v89.25c0,20.4,17.85,38.25,38.25,38.25s38.25-17.85,38.25-38.25v-89.25    h51v89.25c0,20.4,17.85,38.25,38.25,38.25s38.25-17.85,38.25-38.25v-89.25h25.5c15.3,0,25.5-10.2,25.5-25.5v-255h-306V458.363z     M88.932,203.363c-20.4,0-38.25,17.851-38.25,38.25v178.5c0,20.4,17.85,38.25,38.25,38.25s38.25-17.85,38.25-38.25v-178.5    C127.182,221.213,109.332,203.363,88.932,203.363z M522.432,203.363c-20.4,0-38.25,17.851-38.25,38.25v178.5    c0,20.4,17.85,38.25,38.25,38.25s38.25-17.85,38.25-38.25v-178.5C560.682,221.213,542.832,203.363,522.432,203.363z     M394.932,55.463l33.15-33.15c5.1-5.1,5.1-12.75,0-17.85c-5.101-5.101-12.75-5.101-17.851,0l-38.25,38.25    c-17.85-12.75-40.8-17.851-66.3-17.851s-48.45,5.101-68.85,15.3l-35.7-38.25c-5.1-2.55-15.3-2.55-20.4,0    c-2.55,5.101-2.55,15.301,0,20.4l33.15,33.15c-35.7,28.05-61.2,71.399-61.2,122.399h306    C458.682,126.863,433.182,80.963,394.932,55.463z M254.682,126.863h-25.5v-25.5h25.5V126.863z M382.182,126.863h-25.5v-25.5h25.5    V126.863z" >
      </g>    
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="row">
  <svg class="icon" alt="SO" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
   <use xlink:href="#ico-and" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"></use>
  </svg>
  <p>System</p>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/chicoxin/pen/EpdMQj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct the viewBox, its also wrong in the first SVG.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid 1px;
}

svg.icon {
  border: solid 1px tomato;
  /**debug*/
  overflow: visible;
}

.icon use {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none" viewBox="0 0 600 600" width="24" height="24"> 
<defs>
<g id="ico-and" >
        <path  d="M152.682,458.363c0,15.3,10.2,25.5,25.5,25.5h25.5v89.25c0,20.4,17.85,38.25,38.25,38.25s38.25-17.85,38.25-38.25v-89.25    h51v89.25c0,20.4,17.85,38.25,38.25,38.25s38.25-17.85,38.25-38.25v-89.25h25.5c15.3,0,25.5-10.2,25.5-25.5v-255h-306V458.363z     M88.932,203.363c-20.4,0-38.25,17.851-38.25,38.25v178.5c0,20.4,17.85,38.25,38.25,38.25s38.25-17.85,38.25-38.25v-178.5    C127.182,221.213,109.332,203.363,88.932,203.363z M522.432,203.363c-20.4,0-38.25,17.851-38.25,38.25v178.5    c0,20.4,17.85,38.25,38.25,38.25s38.25-17.85,38.25-38.25v-178.5C560.682,221.213,542.832,203.363,522.432,203.363z     M394.932,55.463l33.15-33.15c5.1-5.1,5.1-12.75,0-17.85c-5.101-5.101-12.75-5.101-17.851,0l-38.25,38.25    c-17.85-12.75-40.8-17.851-66.3-17.851s-48.45,5.101-68.85,15.3l-35.7-38.25c-5.1-2.55-15.3-2.55-20.4,0    c-2.55,5.101-2.55,15.301,0,20.4l33.15,33.15c-35.7,28.05-61.2,71.399-61.2,122.399h306    C458.682,126.863,433.182,80.963,394.932,55.463z M254.682,126.863h-25.5v-25.5h25.5V126.863z M382.182,126.863h-25.5v-25.5h25.5    V126.863z" />
      </g>    
      </defs>
</svg>

<div class="row">
  <svg class="icon" alt="SO" viewBox="0 0 600 600" width="24" height="24">
   <use xlink:href="#ico-and"></use>
  </svg>
  <p>System</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks!! i am learning very things about svg now.
Why are second pair values 600?

Comment: @Zawarudo viewbox is related to the value you are using in the path .. you have values that goes over 600 so the view box should cover the path then width/height will control the size